# Compare Two Tables and Insert New Record Even When Any Value Changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to this and I need help. I have two these two tables I need to compare and insert new row if any value is changes or new record appears.
Table `Product` has Primary Key `ID`:

```
ID  | ProductCode | [ProductType] | [Margin]
005 | A320        | GAS           | 0.05
006 | A110        | DIS           | 0.15
007 | A310        | GAS           | 0.04
```

And table `ProductHistory`:

```
ID  | ProductCode | ProductType | Margin   | Version
006 | A110        | DIS         | 1.01     | 1
005 | A320        | GAS         | 0.05     | 0
006 | A110        | DIS         | 0.15     | 0
007 | A310        | GAS         | 0.04     | 0
```

Table `ProductHistory` keeps all records of any changes of table `Product`. Every time there is any change, column `[Version]` in table `ProductHistory` increment by 1.

I'm writing a `MERGE` statement to check if there are any new changes in table `Product` then insert new row in table `[ProductHistory]` and update `[Version]` number.

Here is my current code

```
MERGE [ProductHistory] AS t
    USING dbo.[Product] AS s
        ON t.[ID] = s.[ID]   
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductType], [Margin], [Version])
        VALUES (s.[Id], s.[ProductCode], s.[ProductType], s.[Margin], 0)
   WHEN MATCHED
        AND (t.[ProductCode] <> s.[ProductCode] OR
             t.[ProductType] <> s.[ProductType] OR
             t.[Margin] <> s.[Margin])
      THEN 
        UPDATE
          SET [ID] = s.[ID]
              ,[ProductCode] = s.[ProductCode]
              ,[ProductType] = s.[ProductType]
              ,[Margin] = s.[Margin]
              ,[Version] = t.[Version] + 1
```

So far my code run into problems:

1. I need to compare value in table `Product` with value in `ProductHistory` with the greatest [Version] number (Has not been solved in the code yet)
2. When `ID` matches but values change, I need to insert new record and increment [Version] by one. But this code is not doing what it is supposed to do.

Any help or suggestions on how to fix these help! Thank you

Comment: Sql Server does this for you out-of-the-box with no need to write your own code, using *system versioning*.

Comment: This is a class project so I can't use built-in function like this. @Stu

Comment: Fair enough, in which case you simply need a `trigger` on your `Products` table for Insert and Update. I also wouldn't be using `merge` and trying to maintain a version number, just insert a row in the history for every insert or update in order to have complete visibility; I would still look at what the database does for you for *system versioning* and follow the principle.

Comment: I don't think your approach matches the idea of "history". In most implementations, you record every "version" of a row. Here you appear to only track the "prior" version of a row. Is that really your goal? That seems to be the underlying schema implementation but merge won't work in this case since any change results in a new "version" inserted into the history table.

Comment: @Stu I can see that they want to maintain only changes in history, and not every update.

Comment: @silver_comet, can you provide sqlfiddle with the DDLs to make it easier to respond? Which database are you targeting? Merge is not supported by all DBs AFAIK.

Comment: @pratyahara overwriting data in a history tracking table makes no sense. A history table should contain a row for each and every activity, you then report on it as required.

Comment: @Stu agreed that is normally the case, especially if you are tracking audit info as well. What is in the OP is the latest value and a version history for each ProductID, where it does make sense to write just the change. Moreover, note that this is a contrived class project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on it. Seems to work fine.

```
insert into ProductHistory (ID, ProductCode, ProductType, Margin, Version)
select 
    p.ID, 
    p.ProductCode, 
    p.ProductType, 
    p.Margin, 
    case when ph.Version is null then 0 else ph.Version + 1 end as Version
from Product p
left outer join (
    -- Latest version
    select ID, ProductCode, ProductType, Margin, Version
    from (
        select *,
            row_number() over (partition by ID order by Version desc) as rn
        from ProductHistory
    ) ph
    where rn = 1
) ph on p.id = ph.id
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from ProductHistory
    where ph.id = p.id
      and ph.ProductCode = p.ProductCode 
      and ph.ProductType = p.ProductType
      and ph.Margin = p.Margin
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was able to create a trigger to automatically update table ProductHistory every time there is any changes in table Product.